# Memory allocation of constants and statics in structure?

Tags: microcontroller, c, texas-instruments, compiler, ti-ccstudio

I am working on IIR Filter implementation where I am initializing filter coefficients and memory (form-2 w) memory as follows.

```
typedef struct
{
const _iq b_coeff[NUM_OF_COEFF];
const _iq a_coeff[NUM_OF_COEFF];
_iq w[NUM_OF_COEFF];
}IIR_FILTER;
```

Since, there are constants and static variables in structure. Usually compiler allocates Constants in FLASH (.cinit) and static in RAM (.ebss). [I am using CCS Compiler with TMS320F28033 if that helps ]

So, My question is how will the compiler allocate this since its a structure.

Comment: This is something you can easily check yourself by compiling and looking in the map file. And you can even share your findings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler can't split the memory allocation for your struct between RAM and FLASH.
Any struct variables you create with that type will be located wherever you tell the compiler to put the entire struct, so:
`IIR_FILTER  f1;` will be in RAM, and
`const IIR_FILTER  f2;` will be in FLASH.

However, if the struct is located in RAM (like `f1` above), you compiler should give you an error if you try to assign a value to any member declared as `const`, so:
`f1.b_coeff[0] = 5;` should produce a compiler error, even though f1 is located in RAM.

I'm assuming that the reason you would want to do something like this is to save on RAM usage.
A technique you could use which may work for you would be something like:

```
typedef struct
{
    const _iq * const b_coeff;
    const _iq * const a_coeff;
    _iq w[NUM_OF_COEFF];
} IIR_FILTER;

const _iq b_coeff_const[NUM_OF_COEFF];
const _iq a_coeff_const[NUM_OF_COEFF];
```

and then when you declare the struct variable:
`IIR_FILTER f1 = {.b_coeff = b_coeff_const, .a_coeff = a_coeff_const};`

This way you're only keeping the pointers to the arrays in RAM, while the arrays themselves are in FLASH.
Since C treats arrays and pointers pretty much the same, you can use the pointers as if they were arrays, but you'd lose any bounds-checking which your compiler may provide - so make sure you don't read past the end of the arrays.

Comment: Just curious, what do you think the penalty for this would be in terms of cycles lost in addressing? I'm asking because even though you're working with pointers, you still need to pass the addresses, in both RAM and flash.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with your architecture or compiler, but using GCC on ARM if you initialized the const fields to anything non-zero the whole structure would be allocated both in flash (non-zero initialization) and in RAM (non-const, at least partially).

Non-zero initialization values must be stored in flash while non-const stuff must be in RAM. Aaaand the C standard requires that the structure is placed in continous memory. Try splitting this structure into two parts and see if your program size changes. Or just setting the whole structure as const.